# filter div for hide with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How to filter div for hide with jQuery ?

```
<div class='one'>
    <div class='four'>
        <div class='two'></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='two'></div>
<div class='there'>
    <div class='four'></div>
</div>
<div class='four'></div>
```

I need filter div where class.I've tried the following:

```
var fields = '.two,.four';
$('.field-item div:contains(' + fields + ')').hide();
```

or

```
var fields = '.two,.four';
$('.field-item').filter('div:choices(' + fields + ')');
```

not worked. Why?

Comment: `:contains()` checks the text content of the DIV, not the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you want is right in your question: `.filter`.

```
$(".field-item div").filter(fields).hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

This task can be made extremely simple with jQuery's `$` function with the context parameter. [[docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context)]

```
var fields = '.two,.four';
$(fields, '.field-item div').hide();
```